# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 212 unexpected '('

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 212 unexpected '('.

SQL query is :

```
select distinct 
    ACAP_ID,
    first_value(Account) over (partition by ACAP_ID order by Account desc) as Account,
    Bank,
    first_value(Type) over (partition by ACAP_ID order by Type desc) as Type 
from 
    (select distinct 
         a.RCL_APPLICATION_ID as ACAP_ID,
         zeroifnull(try_cast(a.RCL_ACCT_NUMBER as int)) as Account,
         case b.APP_BANK_NUMBER
             when 1 then 'Bank of Omaha'
             when 4 then 'Bank of Colorado'
             when 20 then 'Bank Illinois'
             when 30 then 'Bank Fremont'
             when 42 then 'Bank Texas'
             when 70 then 'Bank Platte Valley'
             when 76 then 'Bank Kansas'
             when 78 then 'Bank Columbus'
             when 79 then 'Bank North Platte'
             when 83 then 'Bank South Dakota'
         end as Bank,
         a.RCL_OPEN_END_LINE_OF_CRD as Type
     from 
         VW_ACP_QACAPI58 as a
     join 
         VW_ACP_MCDSMG3I as b on a.RCL_APPLICATION_ID = b.APPLICATION_ID 
     where 
         a.RCL_APPLICATION_ID in (20220901251080)
         and a.IS_CUR_FL = 'Y'
         and b.IS_CUR_FL = 'Y')
```

The failure comes up on the `'('` by:

```
Type from (select
```

Please help, not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Do you need to alias the subquery. select blah blah from (your subquery)z.

Answer (score 1):

Each statement should be terminated by `;` and table alias is recommended.

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
     ....
     )  AS t;
```

To extend, it is possible to have a query without a table alias though providing one is a good practice:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think we may need more information. A mocked up version of your SQL works

```
with VW_ACP_QACAPI58(RCL_APPLICATION_ID,RCL_ACCT_NUMBER,RCL_OPEN_END_LINE_OF_CRD,IS_CUR_FL) as
(select * from values
 (20220901251080,'100',200,'Y')
),
VW_ACP_MCDSMG3I(APP_BANK_NUMBER,APPLICATION_ID,IS_CUR_FL) as
(select * from values
 (1,20220901251080,'Y')
)
select distinct 
    ACAP_ID,
    first_value(Account) over (partition by ACAP_ID order by Account desc) as Account,
    Bank,
    first_value(Type) over (partition by ACAP_ID order by Type desc) as Type 
from 
    (select distinct 
         a.RCL_APPLICATION_ID as ACAP_ID,
         zeroifnull(try_cast(a.RCL_ACCT_NUMBER as int)) as Account,
         case b.APP_BANK_NUMBER
             when 1 then 'Bank of Omaha'
             when 4 then 'Bank of Colorado'
             when 20 then 'Bank Illinois'
             when 30 then 'Bank Fremont'
             when 42 then 'Bank Texas'
             when 70 then 'Bank Platte Valley'
             when 76 then 'Bank Kansas'
             when 78 then 'Bank Columbus'
             when 79 then 'Bank North Platte'
             when 83 then 'Bank South Dakota'
         end as Bank,
         a.RCL_OPEN_END_LINE_OF_CRD as Type
     from 
         VW_ACP_QACAPI58 as a
     join 
         VW_ACP_MCDSMG3I as b on a.RCL_APPLICATION_ID = b.APPLICATION_ID 
     where 
         a.RCL_APPLICATION_ID in (20220901251080)
         and a.IS_CUR_FL = 'Y'
         and b.IS_CUR_FL = 'Y')
```

| ACAP_ID | ACCOUNT | BANK | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220901251080 | 100 | Bank of Omaha | 200 |

Answer (score 0):

After ')' at the end, table alias is needed.

```
...'Y') AS A
```

Comment: table aliases are not required, they are very good to use, but not required in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

So using Dave's excellent demo data, this SQL can be rewritten to use a single GROUP BY (the same thing as the two DISTINCT) and it point towards a couple of what I believe are errors in your SQL

So it can be written:

```
with vw_acp_qacapi58(rcl_application_id, rcl_acct_number, rcl_open_end_line_of_crd, is_cur_fl) as (
    select * from values
    (20220901251080,'100',200,'Y')
), vw_acp_mcdsmg3i(app_bank_number, application_id, is_cur_fl) as (
    select * from values
    (1,20220901251080,'Y')
)
select 
    a.rcl_application_id as acap_id
    ,case b.app_bank_number
         when 1 then 'Bank of Omaha'
         when 4 then 'Bank of Colorado'
         when 20 then 'Bank Illinois'
         when 30 then 'Bank Fremont'
         when 42 then 'Bank Texas'
         when 70 then 'Bank Platte Valley'
         when 76 then 'Bank Kansas'
         when 78 then 'Bank Columbus'
         when 79 then 'Bank North Platte'
         when 83 then 'Bank South Dakota'
     end as Bank
    ,max(zeroifnull(try_to_number(a.rcl_acct_number))) as account
    ,max(a.rcl_open_end_line_of_crd) as type
 from vw_acp_qacapi58 as a
 join vw_acp_mcdsmg3i as b 
    on a.rcl_application_id = b.application_id 
 where 
     a.rcl_application_id in (20220901251080)
     and a.is_cur_fl = 'Y'
     and b.is_cur_fl = 'Y'
 group by 1,2
 order by 1,2;
```

giving:

| ACAP_ID | BANK | ACCOUNT | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220901251080 | Bank of Omaha | 100 | 200 |

The outer FIRST_VALUE's are ordering by the actually value, thus are really finding the MAX, so we can swap for that. But as it stands the account is the highest per ACAP_ID ignoring banks, which is somewhat strange.. thus in my code as the max is per account/bank.

But this SQL does run, so perhaps to others points, if you have many blocks of SQL in the same editor which are not terminated with semi-coloin